# RDS Session Host Role Windows Server 2012

Tags: rds, remoteapp

In our environment our users run our accounting system app as a remoteapp. This is hosted on two vms running on a hyper-v server.

Server 1 Roles:
(Hosts the user sessions running remoteapp)
RD Connection Broker
RD Session Host
RD Gateway
RD Licensing
RD Web Access

Server 2 Roles:
(Has App Installed)
RD Session Host (Grace period expired)

Server 1 is the one that actually seems to host the connections, streaming the app from Server 2 to everyone running the remote app. We've got CALs for Server 1.

Recently, a grace period has expired on Server 2 and we can no longer rdp in. (There are no Remote Desktop License Servers available to provide a license error) We really only need the default 2 user max ability, but I fear since we installed the session host role which I am not certain we really needed (And since it's 'expired' but our remoteapp still functions) that it wasn't necessary to have this role on Server 2. How can I restore our ability to directly RDP into Server 2 when necessary? Is the session host role necessary on Server 2 for our remoteapp to continue to function?

Comment: You can use the /admin switch when RDPing into the server.

Example: server.domain.suffix /admin

This opens a console session on the server.

Do you have the application installed on Server 1?

Comment: Nope, the application is only installed on Server 2. Server 1 hosts all the user sessions running the app though. The admin who originally set this up believed the Session host role was necessary on the server that the application was installed on for Server 1 to be able to access the application.

Comment: Nevermind, in Server 2012 /console and /admin have to affect. If you have the application installed on Server 1, just shutdown Server 2 to confirm that the application still functions and then turn it back on to remove it from the collection. If you don't have licensing then my guess is, you aren't actually connecting anyone to the server.

Comment: What server is your license manager? You can go in and reset the licenses used to buy you some time. Do you know if you have User or Device CALs? The Session Host role does not need to be on that server for it to allow connections to Server 2.

Comment: Server 1 is our license server. What I am not certain of is if Server 2 really needs the session host role. I want to remove it if it's not necessary. It was installed, not sure if it was even necessary in the first place, but when the grace period expired, now no one can rdp into this server. Remote app still works fine from sessions hosted on server 1, and we are correctly licensed for the users using our remoteapp.

Comment: You need to log into Server 1, wait for Server Manager to load, go to Remote Desktop Services, click on Collections and you can view the connections on the right. The connections will show the user and what server they are connected to currently. You definitely need to Session Host role on Server 2 if it has the application installed but you don't need it on Server 1. You can also view the CAL details by opening the Server Manager on Server 1, going to tools in the top right and clicking Terminal Services > Licensing Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow my comments and review why all the licenses are consumed and remove the session host role from Server 1 if it isn't being used (just to make it less confusing to manage).

The Server Manager console on Server 1 will give you everything you need. You might need to add Server 2 into the server group so you can view the entire RDS setup and troubleshoot it.

Comment: Server 1 is hosting sessions though. All of the sessions are seen in the task manager of Server 1, but the application they are running is installed on Server 2. This is what is confusing me.

Comment: Session Host means the users are logging into that server. What kind of application is it? Does it have a traditional installer or does it just run from an .exe file? I think you might be missing the application being installed on Server 1. If you go to Server Manager > Remote Desktop Services > Collections > Select your collection > right click your RemoteApp and select Edit Properties, Where does it say the program is located? From everything you have said so far, Server 2 isn't being used at all.